# Using exscale package

Tags: math-mode, packages, fontsize

How to use `exscale` package for mathematical expressions to enlarge?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exscale}
\begin{document}
I need the big font

\[
  \int_0^1 {\frac{\sqrt x}{2}dx} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can use the [`exscale` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/exscale) to obtain `\Huge` math text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exscale}% http://ctan.org/pkg/excale
\begin{document}
I need the big font
{\Huge
\[
  \int_0^1 {\frac{\sqrt x}{2}dx}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

Without the `exscale` package, not all mathematical elements would not scale properly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I need the big font
{\Huge
\[
  \int_0^1 {\frac{\sqrt x}{2}dx}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you want larger font sizes, it's best to use the `\scalebox{<factor>}{<stuff>}` provided by [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). It scales `<stuff>` by `<factor>` without any additional font requirement. However, since `<stuff>` is boxed, certain kerning functionality may be lost, cause slight problems if used next to other mathematical symbols/text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
I need the big font
\[
  \scalebox{5}{$\displaystyle\int_0^1 {\frac{\sqrt x}{2}dx}$}
\]
\end{document}
```